# Pandas plot line chart of two columns based on grouping in third column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am sure this is simple but I struggle with plotting charts for this dataframe.
I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns of which three columns are Gender, Age, Balance
I want to plot two lines with x-axis = Age, y-axis = Balance and two line in a single charts one for Male and Female based on Balance values for the Age.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Gender': ['M','M','F','M','F','F'],
              'Age':    [20,21,20,30,45,36],
              'Balance':[100,120,42,567,444,50]})
```

In excel, I would pivot and show line chart, which looks as follows
[image]

[Sample data Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E7Sg8snggWIraYzoTfDd-kbd120FtlJv/view?usp=sharing)

Subset of data

```
Age,Gender,Balance
21,Male,"113,810"
32,Male,"1,421"
34,Female,"42,879"
42,Male,"10,912"
24,Male,"40,781"
42,Male,"2,116"
40,Male,"65,534"
58,Male,"21,252"
38,Female,"20,505"
33,Female,"3,428"
25,Female,"38,889"
26,Male,"5,833"
33,Female,"20,504"
59,Male,"114,456"
49,Male,"114,021"
47,Female,"54,589"
27,Male,"23,921"
31,Female,"41,626"
24,Male,"4,912"
44,Male,"35,831"
35,Female,"4,586"
39,Female,"40,305"
47,Male,"5,300"
45,Male,"15,013"
36,Female,"41,442"
44,Male,"58,237"
23,Female,"7,370"
20,Male,"11,624"
38,Female,"63,642"
24,Female,"71,571"
35,Male,"75,613"
38,Female,"44,034"
38,Female,"61,890"
56,Female,"13,251"
55,Female,"35,939"
54,Female,"44,973"
63,Male,"73,461"
26,Male,"20,627"
43,Female,"37,889"
52,Male,"67,682"
37,Male,"39,159"
39,Male,"111,149"
27,Female,"10,481"
27,Female,"27,738"
38,Female,"40,456"
26,Male,"12,994"
40,Female,"57,140"
23,Male,"10,249"
37,Male,"89,120"
37,Female,"48,405"
33,Male,"5,160"
46,Male,"57,365"
32,Male,"24,927"
38,Male,"7,602"
39,Female,"4,120"
51,Male,"10,229"
39,Male,"71,396"
42,Male,"62,923"
31,Male,"15,986"
33,Male,"60,748"
32,Female,"99,806"
33,Male,"80,564"
46,Female,"40,685"
25,Female,"58,714"
44,Female,"12,283"
32,Female,"87,203"
31,Female,"44,162"
37,Female,"54,630"
25,Female,"79,603"
39,Male,"3,734"
39,Male,"52,505"
21,Female,"13,487"
28,Female,"27,008"
38,Female,"33,509"
32,Male,"15,375"
40,Male,"9,875"
36,Female,"42,635"
41,Male,"57,762"
40,Female,"47,518"
27,Female,"39,264"
43,Male,"14,946"
39,Male,"45,135"
33,Female,"14,380"
30,Female,"13,407"
29,Female,"41,237"
46,Male,"29,487"
50,Female,"18,160"
59,Female,"23,550"
52,Male,"45,213"
28,Male,"67,180"
30,Male,"28,912"
34,Female,"111,818"
37,Female,"57,574"
31,Female,717
34,Female,"12,559"
31,Female,"96,203"
32,Female,"51,470"
40,Female,"25,248"
45,Male,"16,423"
26,Female,"14,758"
41,Male,"99,190"
42,Female,"30,474"
33,Male,"2,457"
33,Female,"60,876"
40,Female,"65,947"
37,Female,"5,611"
30,Male,"23,015"
30,Female,"35,117"
35,Male,"41,080"
34,Female,"2,016"
44,Male,"50,015"
33,Female,"41,128"
22,Female,"70,526"
20,Female,"1,488"
33,Male,"30,907"
31,Male,"20,570"
55,Male,"60,036"
51,Male,"90,573"
46,Male,"10,950"
28,Male,"6,729"
45,Male,"68,256"
34,Female,"5,654"
32,Female,"18,897"
62,Male,"53,342"
39,Male,"16,549"
28,Female,"44,349"
38,Female,"19,744"
45,Male,"53,204"
41,Male,"28,710"
58,Male,"23,001"
61,Male,"56,557"
42,Female,"41,572"
36,Female,"61,911"
35,Male,"2,423"
39,Female,"84,925"
39,Male,"39,343"
45,Male,"19,287"
18,Male,"6,507"
45,Male,"35,076"
44,Male,"9,667"
30,Female,"5,357"
53,Male,"67,540"
24,Male,"65,526"
26,Female,"20,774"
27,Female,"23,871"
24,Female,"77,908"
26,Male,"3,209"
33,Female,"72,810"
43,Female,"44,996"
41,Male,"21,536"
36,Female,"10,303"
26,Male,"22,143"
48,Female,"18,739"
54,Female,"18,720"
46,Male,"131,848"
39,Female,"83,260"
38,Male,"64,271"
23,Female,"58,442"
37,Male,"101,697"
33,Female,"9,069"
48,Female,"74,211"
39,Male,"6,572"
19,Female,"30,972"
58,Female,"71,689"
49,Male,"127,883"
41,Female,"21,688"
42,Female,"36,354"
18,Female,"58,142"
42,Male,"35,821"
47,Female,"15,438"
51,Female,"40,918"
35,Male,"63,602"
37,Female,"6,456"
42,Female,"29,385"
50,Male,"92,328"
40,Female,"57,702"
24,Female,"51,952"
53,Male,"9,531"
46,Male,399
44,Male,"61,035"
30,Female,"6,133"
29,Male,"73,217"
40,Female,"7,924"
34,Female,"2,872"
33,Female,"53,715"
38,Female,"28,388"
34,Female,"15,376"
27,Male,"23,502"
31,Female,"21,282"
35,Male,"66,567"
31,Male,"79,744"
25,Male,"8,518"
43,Female,"82,248"
52,Male,"22,436"
56,Female,"46,034"
44,Male,"6,498"
43,Male,"64,483"
27,Female,"98,541"
34,Male,"61,421"
39,Male,"51,333"
32,Male,"30,923"
31,Female,"21,890"
45,Male,"10,273"
52,Male,"96,808"
31,Male,"34,008"
40,Female,"22,671"
49,Male,"32,144"
49,Male,"68,252"
22,Male,"10,472"
33,Female,"22,387"
57,Male,"50,454"
50,Female,"57,622"
40,Female,"18,379"
38,Male,"47,824"
32,Female,"79,617"
50,Male,"70,840"
53,Male,"33,269"
34,Female,"28,272"
30,Male,"18,150"
45,Male,"16,824"
51,Male,"25,861"
38,Male,"39,702"
35,Male,"83,727"
42,Male,"65,655"
53,Male,"71,478"
22,Female,"30,117"
29,Female,"15,392"
37,Male,"66,522"
42,Female,"30,630"
33,Female,"35,636"
18,Male,"38,879"
29,Male,"20,969"
45,Male,"74,230"
58,Male,"61,365"
34,Female,"24,796"
28,Female,"34,535"
38,Female,"18,169"
54,Male,"87,050"
56,Male,"20,747"
32,Male,"37,564"
33,Male,"93,525"
41,Female,"3,786"
53,Male,"44,740"
33,Female,"83,889"
47,Male,"8,395"
33,Female,"33,670"
31,Female,"34,515"
34,Male,"44,552"
46,Male,"47,074"
51,Male,"17,188"
22,Male,837
25,Female,"16,380"
45,Female,"9,490"
40,Male,919
46,Male,"46,084"
45,Male,"85,726"
24,Male,"78,004"
32,Male,"97,377"
37,Male,69
28,Male,"2,511"
32,Female,"74,530"
47,Male,"24,930"
38,Male,"69,471"
51,Female,"10,872"
47,Male,"17,538"
28,Female,"34,796"
45,Male,"62,071"
54,Male,"8,844"
52,Male,"17,953"
41,Male,"37,768"
52,Female,"45,693"
33,Male,"1,657"
34,Female,"84,823"
52,Male,"19,187"
36,Male,"61,120"
35,Male,"36,442"
29,Female,"57,983"
36,Male,"65,227"
40,Male,"38,087"
25,Female,"130,797"
42,Female,"1,081"
35,Female,"22,134"
29,Female,"31,495"
36,Male,"44,399"
36,Female,"15,461"
41,Male,"67,100"
33,Female,"20,019"
31,Male,"20,938"
43,Female,"57,420"
44,Female,"19,645"
40,Male,"79,434"
34,Female,"10,218"
34,Female,"76,181"
31,Female,"20,304"
42,Female,"38,638"
54,Male,"55,672"
37,Male,"44,096"
27,Male,"37,191"
33,Female,"20,359"
47,Female,"24,797"
38,Female,"95,477"
52,Male,"51,689"
47,Male,"71,446"
43,Male,"30,323"
39,Male,"54,165"
35,Male,"93,787"
28,Female,"73,859"
30,Female,"73,490"
34,Male,"7,729"
30,Male,"21,157"
42,Female,"22,298"
35,Female,"14,360"
28,Female,"6,921"
58,Male,"27,878"
47,Female,"29,481"
53,Male,"15,668"
50,Male,"2,347"
40,Female,"24,435"
41,Male,"53,685"
33,Male,"60,205"
49,Female,"26,688"
59,Female,"29,417"
42,Female,"61,134"
32,Female,"20,852"
25,Female,"86,275"
61,Female,"75,200"
28,Male,"28,240"
34,Female,"107,641"
56,Male,"48,707"
39,Female,"107,680"
33,Male,"3,226"
35,Male,"56,611"
44,Female,"74,948"
29,Female,"4,406"
32,Female,"12,013"
27,Female,"51,197"
31,Male,"28,265"
37,Male,"22,457"
24,Male,"5,880"
32,Female,"55,945"
57,Female,"55,886"
36,Male,"9,352"
33,Female,"49,665"
58,Male,"41,285"
46,Female,"55,535"
40,Female,"2,619"
31,Female,"24,845"
45,Male,"11,565"
51,Female,"11,909"
38,Male,"48,959"
47,Male,"14,703"
43,Male,"35,417"
26,Female,"10,054"
46,Female,"32,324"
37,Female,"34,072"
51,Male,"41,266"
57,Male,"60,086"
39,Female,"84,480"
27,Female,"27,565"
47,Male,"59,432"
38,Female,"15,926"
44,Female,"5,032"
59,Female,"44,326"
25,Male,"44,277"
31,Male,"71,267"
35,Female,"6,083"
48,Male,"66,005"
60,Male,"22,067"
33,Female,"15,196"
27,Male,"45,374"
26,Female,"21,988"
33,Male,"59,890"
42,Female,"62,850"
38,Male,"24,965"
43,Female,"10,959"
49,Female,"68,026"
44,Male,"82,950"
33,Male,"76,301"
46,Female,"33,779"
46,Female,"24,686"
27,Male,"16,613"
43,Male,"55,988"
50,Male,"67,763"
60,Female,"5,916"
47,Male,"36,493"
45,Female,"27,955"
32,Male,"6,471"
47,Male,"62,781"
35,Male,"36,572"
55,Female,"22,099"
41,Male,"41,511"
33,Female,"68,170"
28,Male,"94,339"
51,Female,"43,954"
41,Male,"25,288"
26,Female,"37,830"
32,Female,"76,207"
28,Female,"35,052"
32,Male,"6,080"
55,Male,"20,815"
48,Male,"73,399"
42,Female,"4,250"
35,Male,"39,044"
30,Male,"19,604"
33,Male,"15,660"
29,Female,"99,271"
34,Female,"20,742"
38,Female,"25,016"
34,Male,919
29,Male,"15,560"
43,Female,"7,670"
17,Female,"13,301"
39,Male,"91,246"
34,Male,"59,162"
41,Female,"58,683"
62,Female,"23,578"
31,Female,"25,016"
34,Male,"10,309"
39,Female,"31,777"
29,Female,"16,056"
40,Male,"24,646"
30,Male,"68,927"
37,Male,"32,570"
34,Male,"111,798"
61,Male,"105,354"
38,Male,"29,679"
35,Female,"88,873"
44,Male,242
32,Female,"72,238"
33,Female,"16,867"
27,Male,"6,825"
36,Female,"6,272"
32,Male,"11,297"
35,Male,"71,961"
40,Male,"17,616"
33,Female,"32,418"
35,Male,"125,015"
38,Female,"18,578"
28,Female,"31,066"
37,Male,"5,234"
37,Male,"28,244"
35,Male,"8,167"
44,Male,"30,778"
19,Male,"9,758"
55,Male,"31,708"
47,Male,"65,701"
40,Female,"37,204"
36,Female,"49,294"
46,Male,"49,511"
35,Female,"31,392"
45,Male,"39,198"
41,Male,"25,581"
40,Male,"67,327"
37,Male,"59,430"
38,Male,"77,710"
41,Male,"84,302"
49,Female,"92,941"
32,Female,"5,709"
59,Female,"87,136"
27,Male,"20,963"
30,Male,"32,676"
52,Male,"23,112"
31,Male,"31,181"
54,Male,"90,166"
21,Female,"11,236"
32,Female,"41,881"
34,Male,"58,648"
48,Male,"1,208"
52,Male,"59,450"
40,Female,"33,801"
38,Female,"14,400"
29,Male,"106,821"
37,Female,"43,420"
38,Female,"51,616"
50,Female,"99,770"
17,Male,"5,158"
32,Male,"13,668"
27,Female,"57,283"
51,Male,"4,188"
60,Male,"74,666"
51,Male,"53,537"
29,Male,"32,447"
43,Male,"15,879"
52,Male,"13,419"
53,Female,"51,621"
40,Male,"3,615"
37,Female,"122,248"
39,Female,"16,956"
34,Female,"1,090"
30,Male,"33,024"
29,Female,"69,174"
23,Female,"2,092"
44,Male,"86,652"
46,Male,"91,216"
25,Female,"5,834"
43,Female,"40,730"
53,Female,"19,634"
27,Male,"40,625"
36,Male,"65,592"
32,Female,"30,225"
45,Male,"41,160"
34,Female,"23,145"
28,Female,"38,920"
49,Male,"42,654"
44,Male,"53,325"
31,Male,"8,857"
38,Female,"114,945"
35,Male,"33,042"
23,Male,"40,230"
27,Male,"17,541"
31,Female,"46,207"
37,Male,"54,533"
26,Male,"8,708"
33,Male,"18,305"
26,Male,"12,883"
37,Female,"7,467"
55,Male,"10,903"
36,Female,"23,247"
47,Male,"26,891"
37,Female,"60,167"
52,Male,"104,693"
24,Female,"86,123"
48,Male,"35,874"
38,Male,"89,551"
31,Male,"124,232"
41,Male,"52,335"
43,Male,"36,109"
43,Female,"36,694"
42,Male,"112,917"
42,Male,"19,473"
28,Male,"32,031"
47,Female,"86,222"
45,Female,"4,151"
39,Female,"21,272"
42,Male,"96,088"
36,Male,"64,281"
64,Female,"23,522"
61,Male,"4,926"
32,Female,"71,324"
26,Male,"64,330"
29,Male,"31,044"
51,Male,879
45,Male,"18,035"
28,Female,"40,163"
34,Male,"19,053"
23,Male,"5,257"
57,Female,"34,948"
41,Male,"112,243"
44,Female,"46,153"
41,Male,"57,520"
21,Female,"45,899"
18,Female,"36,706"
30,Male,"32,400"
40,Male,"80,678"
56,Female,"25,452"
35,Male,"9,465"
47,Female,"48,268"
45,Female,"20,228"
42,Female,"19,699"
47,Female,"10,671"
29,Male,"30,556"
30,Female,"54,749"
34,Female,"24,827"
48,Male,"51,202"
48,Male,"4,363"
38,Female,"7,148"
33,Female,"74,578"
52,Female,"27,309"
43,Female,"88,279"
51,Male,"20,981"
34,Male,"12,137"
38,Female,"49,606"
26,Male,"7,685"
25,Female,"47,846"
28,Female,"12,085"
37,Male,"6,591"
30,Female,"72,874"
47,Male,"115,722"
61,Male,"7,992"
53,Male,"44,984"
33,Female,"56,539"
19,Female,"15,278"
44,Male,"8,128"
48,Female,"36,947"
30,Female,"51,991"
28,Male,"6,016"
38,Male,"49,172"
50,Male,"12,610"
52,Male,"37,817"
29,Female,"32,458"
27,Male,"1,387"
34,Male,"43,670"
49,Female,"39,552"
36,Female,"37,585"
31,Male,"12,728"
28,Female,"142,461"
39,Female,"18,016"
53,Female,"37,604"
37,Female,"21,823"
25,Male,"11,186"
34,Male,"57,914"
38,Female,"42,816"
54,Female,"17,076"
33,Male,"37,752"
39,Male,"32,430"
25,Female,"29,644"
38,Male,"49,610"
38,Female,"52,220"
34,Male,"25,949"
59,Female,"14,569"
34,Female,"52,702"
37,Female,"7,355"
53,Male,"43,176"
34,Female,"97,934"
33,Male,"95,833"
30,Female,"45,527"
33,Male,"43,473"
31,Male,"58,911"
27,Female,"40,857"
57,Male,"69,281"
26,Male,"57,623"
28,Female,"20,894"
48,Male,"55,410"
55,Male,"71,796"
26,Female,"31,028"
46,Male,"47,359"
37,Female,"74,238"
19,Male,"75,913"
32,Male,"10,728"
33,Female,"14,301"
47,Male,"59,561"
34,Female,"95,423"
36,Male,"9,780"
50,Male,"67,946"
43,Male,"83,943"
28,Female,"31,153"
36,Female,"23,749"
49,Female,"31,505"
24,Female,"3,140"
32,Male,"19,407"
31,Female,"16,392"
57,Female,"20,516"
32,Female,"48,145"
38,Male,"21,765"
33,Male,"19,294"
49,Female,"2,994"
21,Male,"10,248"
50,Male,"2,470"
41,Male,"89,366"
31,Male,"70,156"
54,Male,"11,561"
35,Female,"44,438"
33,Male,"28,681"
31,Female,"130,717"
53,Male,"11,375"
37,Male,"22,841"
35,Male,"33,838"
39,Female,"76,736"
43,Male,"10,301"
28,Male,"94,767"
39,Female,"76,608"
39,Female,"4,157"
27,Male,"10,223"
51,Male,"27,770"
63,Male,"53,004"
41,Male,"4,657"
26,Male,"80,850"
30,Female,"12,356"
49,Female,"1,602"
49,Female,"62,026"
53,Female,"56,872"
31,Female,"8,261"
43,Male,"11,880"
25,Female,"54,930"
36,Male,"45,626"
44,Female,"19,326"
60,Male,"59,183"
31,Male,"29,371"
29,Male,"12,258"
29,Male,"70,086"
64,Female,"24,729"
34,Female,"55,297"
21,Male,"16,696"
28,Female,"82,638"
38,Male,"98,022"
64,Male,"14,558"
47,Male,"26,087"
36,Male,"59,127"
29,Female,"41,897"
51,Male,"62,064"
51,Female,"55,056"
38,Female,"86,892"
25,Male,"2,126"
40,Female,"72,020"
34,Male,"41,060"
32,Female,"79,292"
31,Male,"59,589"
48,Male,"39,883"
36,Female,"66,084"
28,Male,"65,994"
48,Male,"45,705"
59,Male,"24,989"
27,Male,"47,857"
33,Male,920
39,Female,"45,969"
34,Male,"18,952"
38,Female,"95,608"
47,Female,"38,258"
62,Female,"110,171"
38,Female,"23,527"
36,Male,"53,759"
30,Female,"8,100"
21,Female,"113,673"
43,Female,"38,986"
40,Male,"37,247"
45,Male,"55,276"
53,Female,"56,122"
27,Female,"18,601"
36,Male,"39,384"
61,Male,"32,439"
46,Male,"7,532"
31,Female,"61,587"
29,Male,"76,517"
32,Male,"54,090"
28,Female,"88,090"
28,Female,"39,597"
43,Female,"9,130"
36,Female,"27,081"
32,Male,"3,103"
28,Female,"94,793"
32,Male,"64,701"
45,Female,"12,508"
18,Male,840
27,Male,"33,355"
43,Male,"33,132"
55,Female,"77,113"
29,Female,"7,614"
24,Female,"66,857"
33,Male,"61,877"
29,Female,"119,118"
37,Male,"12,160"
39,Female,"19,383"
46,Male,"29,407"
22,Female,"32,946"
31,Female,"63,449"
42,Female,"17,631"
34,Male,"48,947"
31,Male,"38,361"
24,Male,"52,872"
19,Male,"30,691"
61,Female,"18,880"
45,Male,"64,665"
51,Female,"16,321"
43,Female,"10,037"
61,Female,"48,394"
33,Male,"38,089"
26,Male,"58,399"
22,Male,"14,748"
36,Female,"84,942"
33,Female,133
49,Female,"34,393"
29,Male,"34,290"
36,Female,"49,350"
45,Male,"48,333"
49,Male,875
45,Male,"10,899"
37,Female,"59,970"
28,Male,"11,825"
34,Female,"22,433"
49,Male,"75,620"
64,Male,"10,325"
20,Female,"32,823"
19,Female,"63,979"
27,Male,"54,644"
40,Male,"71,368"
45,Female,"59,349"
53,Female,"41,704"
54,Male,"34,782"
36,Male,"144,209"
40,Male,"29,733"
41,Male,"10,486"
22,Female,"84,123"
50,Male,"26,318"
47,Male,"14,273"
64,Male,"139,415"
59,Female,"6,674"
32,Female,"19,954"
33,Female,"4,575"
49,Male,"4,735"
37,Male,"91,665"
33,Male,"23,676"
38,Male,"43,582"
46,Male,"12,483"
39,Female,"100,130"
24,Female,"17,347"
46,Female,"112,571"
45,Female,"12,247"
30,Male,"20,821"
45,Male,"81,068"
55,Male,"28,781"
21,Female,"50,686"
43,Male,"31,840"
34,Male,"21,360"
52,Male,"47,271"
51,Female,"5,467"
32,Female,"50,111"
33,Female,"46,035"
28,Male,"23,076"
31,Male,"79,314"
36,Male,"23,291"
40,Male,"12,622"
32,Male,"16,127"
33,Male,"39,625"
28,Female,"76,304"
58,Male,"31,082"
50,Male,"21,885"
27,Male,"7,385"
25,Female,"5,490"
28,Female,"19,866"
38,Female,"67,842"
34,Male,"99,934"
36,Female,"51,614"
35,Female,"39,047"
61,Male,"35,341"
31,Male,"56,801"
47,Male,"63,746"
37,Male,"27,526"
20,Female,"74,880"
53,Female,"12,769"
42,Male,"5,436"
24,Female,"16,527"
38,Female,"33,589"
36,Female,"111,371"
56,Male,"21,196"
28,Male,"102,952"
41,Male,"28,479"
30,Male,"2,603"
41,Female,"36,174"
46,Male,"76,601"
44,Male,"6,697"
20,Female,"9,707"
31,Female,"20,953"
27,Male,"8,121"
39,Female,"33,703"
47,Male,"17,274"
54,Male,"96,381"
35,Male,"136,365"
37,Male,"118,379"
36,Male,"41,643"
52,Male,"34,118"
43,Female,"29,990"
24,Male,"5,396"
25,Female,"20,412"
29,Male,"11,246"
59,Female,"28,221"
30,Male,"42,008"
28,Male,"33,551"
32,Female,"89,329"
31,Male,"26,913"
40,Female,"1,949"
44,Male,"23,676"
32,Female,"51,208"
33,Male,"9,987"
35,Male,"76,480"
35,Female,"2,120"
32,Female,"27,985"
51,Male,"24,745"
44,Male,"65,479"
22,Female,"18,299"
38,Male,"90,250"
38,Male,"83,131"
44,Male,"18,393"
35,Male,"12,813"
31,Female,"81,245"
45,Female,"81,370"
35,Female,"10,708"
24,Male,"56,070"
41,Male,"25,407"
41,Male,"60,076"
15,Female,"12,548"
40,Female,"52,735"
36,Female,"52,050"
39,Male,"30,238"
50,Male,"6,844"
52,Female,"53,599"
43,Female,"50,078"
45,Female,"101,994"
25,Male,"73,869"
52,Male,"13,536"
47,Female,"9,169"
38,Female,"31,728"
40,Male,"2,559"
38,Female,"39,171"
27,Female,"23,183"
36,Male,"61,333"
57,Male,"42,706"
31,Male,"42,471"
39,Female,"34,441"
57,Male,"106,232"
25,Male,"22,186"
23,Female,"20,148"
45,Male,"48,234"
49,Female,"41,652"
45,Male,"17,520"
35,Female,"23,072"
31,Female,"60,850"
45,Male,"41,348"
46,Female,"50,959"
55,Male,"48,227"
47,Male,"128,488"
36,Female,"39,639"
40,Female,"7,551"
35,Male,"26,058"
30,Male,"30,189"
38,Male,"59,605"
40,Female,"24,726"
28,Male,"69,126"
57,Female,"31,148"
53,Female,"21,717"
36,Female,"33,899"
29,Female,"10,423"
44,Male,"60,462"
29,Male,"26,045"
35,Female,"53,799"
64,Male,"24,994"
53,Male,"44,741"
39,Male,"57,496"
20,Male,"64,855"
26,Male,"24,900"
53,Male,"31,175"
59,Female,"19,630"
45,Female,"38,404"
29,Female,"17,287"
45,Male,"20,407"
30,Male,"22,763"
37,Female,"97,665"
34,Male,"125,975"
22,Female,"16,369"
30,Female,"49,965"
61,Female,"25,267"
35,Male,"5,582"
38,Male,"14,042"
37,Female,"25,191"
39,Female,"58,376"
45,Male,"58,442"
60,Male,"102,409"
50,Male,"65,277"
28,Male,"46,835"
32,Female,"19,510"
46,Male,"22,280"
33,Female,"9,113"
21,Male,"17,595"
36,Female,"3,962"
38,Male,"21,535"
36,Male,"30,047"
41,Male,"7,976"
31,Male,"12,383"
38,Female,"67,598"
59,Male,"37,483"
36,Female,"59,611"
42,Male,"37,456"
37,Male,"44,872"
34,Female,"44,066"
31,Male,"101,731"
45,Male,"85,992"
57,Male,"47,745"
34,Female,"57,068"
38,Male,"106,227"
43,Female,"19,488"
32,Female,"15,858"
37,Male,"60,097"
33,Female,"2,471"
33,Male,"31,959"
43,Male,"31,739"
45,Female,"9,654"
47,Male,"64,172"
32,Female,"26,231"
32,Female,699
36,Female,"98,682"
40,Female,"55,489"
50,Male,"20,397"
55,Male,"66,721"
49,Female,"48,099"
33,Male,"81,827"
52,Female,"55,559"
36,Male,"33,595"
28,Male,"60,496"
34,Female,"74,987"
37,Male,"28,328"
33,Female,"36,017"
25,Female,"71,683"
37,Male,"15,811"
45,Female,"33,898"
31,Female,"6,057"
24,Female,"55,477"
18,Female,"9,281"
52,Female,"16,743"
18,Female,"31,719"
29,Female,"56,296"
30,Male,"15,452"
47,Male,"8,576"
51,Male,"52,186"
43,Female,"33,336"
56,Female,"47,447"
49,Male,"17,312"
36,Male,"17,823"
42,Male,"19,996"
27,Female,"63,257"
37,Female,"37,294"
35,Female,"5,247"
40,Male,"42,462"
28,Female,"62,137"
42,Female,"43,376"
29,Female,"1,834"
49,Male,"83,989"
26,Female,"13,299"
35,Male,"15,908"
51,Female,"52,001"
36,Male,"106,275"
44,Female,"9,209"
25,Female,"1,890"
43,Male,"4,421"
51,Male,"32,448"
40,Female,"22,027"
31,Male,"35,448"
29,Male,"9,567"
29,Female,"34,725"
35,Female,"17,717"
43,Female,"38,308"
51,Female,"5,227"
23,Female,"24,384"
23,Female,"133,589"
24,Female,"93,329"
61,Male,"6,243"
61,Male,"75,638"
32,Male,"43,532"
38,Female,"23,666"
30,Male,"42,732"
34,Male,"42,429"
58,Male,"76,328"
27,Female,"7,835"
51,Male,"62,238"
45,Male,"28,654"
34,Female,"8,456"
46,Female,"4,907"
32,Male,"59,266"
58,Male,"10,786"
40,Female,"19,448"
29,Male,"20,166"
32,Female,"53,274"
38,Female,"66,093"
49,Male,"45,629"
35,Male,"7,139"
33,Female,"21,875"
23,Female,"23,220"
25,Female,"12,589"
35,Female,"3,673"
43,Male,"4,808"
32,Male,"27,316"
55,Female,"18,705"
58,Male,"65,497"
48,Female,"9,758"
31,Female,"23,095"
44,Female,"9,777"
36,Female,"18,925"
28,Male,"13,468"
32,Male,"12,954"
40,Female,"32,051"
40,Male,"55,771"
35,Male,"10,291"
44,Male,"9,161"
58,Male,"79,655"
36,Male,"5,275"
30,Male,"29,283"
45,Male,"38,098"
39,Male,"139,434"
37,Female,"44,335"
29,Female,"71,423"
26,Male,"104,366"
43,Female,"38,012"
37,Male,"45,686"
56,Male,"29,861"
28,Female,"48,124"
34,Male,"18,412"
32,Male,"30,865"
40,Female,"53,697"
37,Female,"26,052"
28,Female,"68,809"
29,Male,"94,523"
36,Female,"84,693"
32,Male,"76,492"
27,Male,"30,268"
42,Male,"11,632"
35,Female,"20,637"
38,Female,"89,126"
38,Male,"21,417"
50,Male,"99,255"
51,Male,"14,724"
51,Male,"37,322"
53,Female,466
46,Male,"47,908"
28,Male,"82,847"
53,Female,"36,319"
28,Female,"59,252"
30,Female,"27,937"
30,Female,"52,474"
22,Male,"25,219"
47,Male,"12,302"
35,Female,"43,833"
50,Male,"17,454"
44,Male,"25,768"
39,Male,"55,146"
48,Female,"35,190"
59,Male,"64,210"
35,Female,"4,012"
37,Female,"51,295"
41,Female,"52,991"
43,Male,"33,234"
47,Female,"3,985"
36,Female,"9,356"
34,Male,"3,716"
35,Male,"37,326"
47,Male,"21,736"
20,Female,"82,598"
41,Female,"4,477"
25,Male,"75,357"
34,Female,"61,576"
41,Female,"42,914"
32,Male,"25,583"
35,Female,"5,603"
42,Male,"71,409"
25,Male,"24,366"
30,Female,279
52,Male,"48,602"
61,Female,"1,409"
32,Male,"21,454"
18,Male,"77,682"
39,Female,"48,514"
19,Female,"2,184"
37,Female,"26,478"
25,Male,"81,820"
50,Female,"39,460"
51,Male,"32,712"
29,Female,"23,049"
35,Female,"92,788"
36,Female,"31,377"
54,Male,"71,935"
34,Male,"43,520"
36,Female,"50,507"
31,Male,"5,178"
36,Male,"30,265"
32,Female,"98,044"
24,Female,"97,846"
51,Male,"4,573"
49,Male,"71,307"
44,Female,"44,752"
37,Female,"24,898"
34,Female,"15,263"
33,Female,"12,547"
43,Male,"53,739"
28,Female,"104,030"
33,Female,"20,517"
44,Female,"11,121"
29,Male,"41,898"
53,Female,"8,313"
43,Male,"30,216"
34,Female,"39,040"
49,Female,"72,613"
31,Male,919
42,Female,"34,017"
40,Female,"47,276"
31,Male,"51,754"
33,Male,"9,165"
28,Female,"31,878"
47,Male,"5,520"
52,Female,"61,901"
32,Female,"37,920"
47,Female,"34,391"
38,Male,"48,829"
37,Male,"8,679"
37,Male,"61,009"
57,Male,"46,060"
40,Male,"43,604"
40,Female,"32,141"
34,Male,"23,744"
36,Female,"41,867"
37,Male,"12,500"
48,Male,"11,862"
48,Male,"21,734"
41,Female,"8,910"
40,Female,"73,177"
40,Female,"50,651"
33,Male,"36,003"
61,Male,"11,242"
48,Male,"65,535"
31,Female,"82,376"
40,Female,"114,118"
41,Female,"82,862"
36,Female,"72,728"
33,Female,"15,241"
33,Male,"73,297"
46,Female,"43,705"
46,Female,"79,599"
33,Male,"45,820"
34,Female,"29,587"
41,Male,"24,913"
48,Male,"43,730"
26,Female,"22,897"
43,Male,"29,782"
33,Male,"20,091"
43,Female,"55,352"
49,Female,"34,375"
31,Female,"92,983"
35,Male,"51,009"
27,Male,"92,610"
58,Male,"28,310"
53,Female,"81,863"
49,Female,"49,277"
41,Female,"19,485"
35,Female,"123,357"
20,Male,"3,715"
41,Male,"17,160"
42,Female,"72,596"
37,Female,"49,587"
34,Female,"77,383"
57,Male,"78,221"
39,Female,"25,974"
28,Male,"40,037"
27,Male,"77,898"
31,Female,"29,943"
53,Female,"47,265"
39,Male,"37,602"
52,Male,"19,297"
54,Male,"26,905"
28,Female,"33,797"
34,Male,"15,746"
24,Male,"25,781"
41,Female,916
36,Female,"125,690"
38,Male,"54,828"
57,Male,"12,857"
46,Male,"3,002"
31,Male,"42,049"
40,Female,"30,815"
28,Female,"13,618"
33,Male,"66,452"
57,Male,"63,027"
22,Male,"40,668"
26,Female,"3,974"
38,Male,"56,516"
37,Female,"81,383"
36,Male,"66,519"
38,Female,"3,876"
27,Female,"42,901"
44,Female,"14,563"
60,Female,"67,913"
61,Male,"55,421"
53,Male,"114,059"
29,Male,"29,909"
45,Female,"86,475"
32,Male,"42,956"
40,Male,"3,890"
32,Male,"17,056"
49,Female,"7,873"
55,Female,"100,995"
48,Male,"54,607"
36,Female,"20,254"
46,Female,"10,394"
36,Female,"88,957"
35,Male,"40,309"
30,Female,"16,703"
29,Male,"25,665"
29,Male,"51,239"
39,Male,"11,024"
42,Male,"30,923"
33,Female,"76,628"
34,Female,"3,682"
44,Male,"161,517"
27,Female,"55,631"
36,Male,"42,161"
46,Male,"87,484"
42,Female,"1,063"
34,Female,"87,664"
38,Female,"2,845"
28,Male,"54,458"
37,Male,"23,108"
33,Male,655
42,Male,"41,989"
36,Male,"7,729"
37,Male,"17,331"
44,Female,"14,635"
34,Female,"32,700"
29,Male,"23,963"
21,Male,"18,508"
38,Male,"27,984"
33,Female,"45,536"
36,Female,"4,867"
35,Female,"26,111"
38,Male,"31,323"
58,Male,"11,925"
45,Male,"3,052"
57,Female,"38,534"
56,Male,"76,278"
24,Male,"7,552"
29,Male,"16,997"
39,Female,"23,208"
33,Male,614
36,Male,"43,385"
54,Female,"12,121"
49,Male,"21,066"
36,Male,"3,890"
33,Female,"30,045"
49,Male,342
59,Male,"17,674"
50,Female,"16,041"
43,Male,"81,498"
23,Male,"117,946"
36,Male,"51,263"
53,Male,"6,989"
42,Male,"55,687"
48,Male,"72,061"
43,Male,"48,270"
23,Male,"7,211"
58,Male,"18,189"
29,Male,"13,910"
36,Male,"24,904"
49,Male,"48,950"
54,Male,"28,430"
38,Male,"63,644"
30,Female,"4,570"
30,Female,"139,784"
41,Female,"28,579"
53,Male,"48,775"
40,Male,"39,935"
46,Male,"85,331"
44,Female,"64,470"
64,Female,"73,503"
50,Female,"59,477"
```

Comment: You can pivot the dataframe as you do in excel. `dfp = df.pivot(...)` - no aggregation or `dfp = df.pivot_table(...)` - with aggregation. Plot with `dfp.plot()`

Comment: Probably `dfp = df.pivot_table(index='Age', columns='Gender', values='Balance', aggfunc='sum')` and then `ax = dfp.plot()`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thank for your replies. I have granted access. 
Your answer is 'almost' good (I did not know this aggfunc and it was complaining of duplicate 'Age'). 
Why 'almost' is cause I am getting funny sum values but that another issue. I will try to figure that out. Thank you for your quick reply

Comment: Given the sample dataframe, the code in the previous comment will do you want. [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47VWz.png)

Comment: Once sec, balance has commas in it

Comment: Read the data in with `df = pd.read_csv('d:/data/cust.csv', index_col=[0], thousands=',')` and then use my code.

Comment: sorry, yes I saw that ...my bad ..apologies .... 
I accept your answer, aggfunc='sum' was the trick

Comment: If you want more labels on the x-axis `ax = dfp.plot(xticks=range(df.Age.unique().min(), df.Age.unique().max() + 1, 2), figsize=(12, 7))`